# Cannot convert object, recieved from ajax call, into a long

Tags: c#, ajax, json, object

I'm using Asp.Net-Mvc, I have this method in my controller:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]    
    public ActionResult LinkAccount(string site, object id)
    {
        return this.Json(id);
    }
```

Here's the ajax method that calls it:

```
$.post("/Account/LinkAccount", { site: "Facebook", 
                               id: FB.Facebook.apiClient.get_session().uid },
        function(result) {
            alert(result); 
        }, "json"
    );
```

returning this.Json(id); makes the alert work... it alerts 7128383 (something similar to that).

but if I change `this.Json(id)` to `this.Json(Conver.ToInt64(id));` the alert does not fire...

Any idea of why I can't convert an object received from an object to a long?

*I already know changing the `LinkAccount` method to accept a long instead works just fine. It's just I need it as an object because some other sites I'm linking up have strings for id's rather than longs.*

**UPDATE:** I tried running the code on localhost so I could set a breakpoint. First I changed the line `return this.Json(Convert.ToInt64(id));` to `long idAsLong = Convert.ToInt64(id));`. Here's what the debugger is telling me:

- When I hover over id it says: "**id | {string[1]}**"
   
  and when I press the plus button is shows: "**[0] | '7128383'**"
- When I hover over idAsLong, it says: "**idAsLong | 0**"

Why isn't it converting it properly?

Comment: what does this.Json do? can it accept Int64?

Comment: so, id is an array of string, which you can't convert to Int64. The 0th element contains the actual ID (which can be converted to Int64).
long idAsLong = Convert.ToInt64(id[0]);

Comment: You were right shahklapesh, except that since id is an object, you cannot use indexes like [0]. Instead, what worked, was this: Convert.ToInt64(((string[])id)[0]). Thanks for your help. If you re-write what you said in an answer I'll accept it to give you the credit/rep for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shahklapesh said:

> so, id is an array of string, which
>   you can't convert to Int64. The 0th
>   element contains the actual ID (which
>   can be converted to Int64). long
>   idAsLong = Convert.ToInt64(id[0]);

Which was correct, except that since id is an object, you cannot use indexes like [0]. Instead, what worked, was this: `Convert.ToInt64(((string[])id)[0])`

Thanks for the help Shahklapesh!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the model knows how to make an object out of the request parameter, so what you get is a null.  Try accepting id as a string and converting it to a long.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]    
public ActionResult LinkAccount(string site, string id)
{
    return this.Json( Convert.ToInt64(id) );
}
```

Or you could leave it as a string, since you're just passing it back via JSON (which will just serialize it back as a string anyway).  You'd only need to do the conversion if  you needed it as a long on the server.